# How to put Apache Thrift behind Boost Asio?

Tags: boost-asio, thrift

As far as I see Thrift documentation/examples/tutorials is very limited. A single example on C++ shows how to attach Thrift handler to a socket. I would like to wrap it into Boost::Asio-based http server.

Please, if somebody have links to some already published experience on this matter, please tell me, I found nothing.

Or, at least, give me a hint, please.

Comment: can you post a link to the C++ example?

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageC%2B%2B